# Remove orphan branch from commit history

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

## The problem

I have a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/ydluo/qdyn) shared with a number of contributors with a relatively long commit history. At some point, I attempted to merge an orphaned branch into the master branch, which didn't work out quite as expected. The result of this attempt is that ever since this merge, all files in the repository appear to have been (re)created in this commit. The commit history tree is still preserved, so at the time I didn't pay too much attention to it (I was more than happy that I finally got this merge to work).

Something I did not realise back then, was that the history of individual files was not preserved. See for instance [this example](https://github.com/ydluo/qdyn/commits/master/src/fault_stress.f90): this file should have a history that goes all the way back to 2012, but this history is not shown past 11 August 2017, when I merged the orphan branch.

## Possible solution?

If I look at the history tree, I see this rogue commit dangling like some kind of appendix, indicated in green in the figure below. Normally it would not be possible to safely `rebase` commits that have already been pushed upstream, without causing mayhem to everybody else. But in this particular situation, would it be possible to either merge or delete this dangling commit, so that the individual file history is recovered? Or is there another solution to safely re-route the version history?

[image: Git history tree]

Comment: Don't you see the whole history (including the lost one) when you run `git log --all` in local?

Comment: @smarber I do see the whole history with `git log --all`, but I do not see the whole file history with `git log -- [filename]`. The individual file history is clipped at the orphan, older file changes are not being displayed. This is an inconvenience when browsing through individual file histories on GitHub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just add a parent to orphan. (this sounds so weird out of context)

First, choose a parent, then replace the commit with `git replace --graft`

```
git replace --graft b1fbc1d21933 de3df2f048c
```

Make sure all is good, git replace will not write any changes, but it should all be good on your instance now.
You can even check the new commit with

```
git for-each-ref
```

If you have your history back and are happy with the result, write the changes with

```
git filter-branch -- --all
```

And force push your new history.

Disclaimer: I have tested this with your repo and it seems to be working fine, but I have never actually done something like this before, it might do unwanted things.

Comment: Great suggestion, Lukas! I have tried it on my local repo, and it indeed seems to work as you described. My main concern, however, is whether or not this method is safe to push upstream (in the same way as a `rebase` works fine locally, but can break your upstream repo). Could you comment on that?

Comment: @MPA Because the history has changed, all branches that exist now will need to get rebased. But there are no actual changes in the files, so this should be no problem. You can try that locally as well and make sure its fine. I can't think of anything else that could go wrong, but again I haven't done this before.